# How to make IE and Firefox display hidden elements the same (IE shifts visible element)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Rendering the same html in IE and Firefox gives me a different result because in IE, the hidden checkbox is not ignored, from a layout perspective.  This image shows that there is a space where the hidden checkbox is in IE, but no space where the hidden checkbox is in Firefox:
[image: image shows that there is a space where the hidden checkbox is in IE, but no space where the hidden checkbox is in Firefox]

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#checkboxhide { position: relative; visibility: hidden; font-size: 8.5pt; font-weight: font-family: verdana;}
//-->
</style>
</head><body>
<table><tr>
<td>|</td>
<td><span id="checkboxhide"><input type="checkbox" hidden="" name="blah"></span>|Greetings Earthings</td>
</tr></table>
</body></html>
```

How can I get the two (or more) browsers to show the same thing?

Comment: visibility leaves space.. use display:none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility) property, when set to `hidden`, can hide the contents of an element, but not the space it occupies.

The [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS%3adisplay) property, when set to `none`, hides both the element's contents and the space it occupies.

Use `display: none` rather than `visibility: hidden`:

```
#checkboxhide { position: relative; display: none; font-size: 8.5pt; font-weight: font-family: verdana;}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  Now, what am I going to to for the next 7 minutes before doing the green check mark?